# Error in Javascript Code in Freecodecamp

Tags: javascript

```
function titleCase(str) {
     var strArr = str.toLowerCase().split(' ');
     var strUp = [str.length];  
     for(var i=0;i<str.length;i++)
     {
        strUp[i] = strArr[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase();
     }

     return strUp.join(' ');  
}

titleCase("I'm a little tea pot");
```

Im stuck at a problem in freecodecamp.

Its displaying:

> Cant read property 'charAt' of undefined".

Comment: Do you know how to open the console in a browser, and how to use `console.log`?

Comment: I'm confused. Does charAt not for array?

Answer (score 2):

= The reason why you are getting `Cant read property 'charAt' of undefined".` is you are using `str.length` on the `for` loop. You should use `strArr.length`. The length of `str` is always bigger than the length of `strArr` and that is why you are getting `undefined` of the last part iteration.

= You should also add `strArr[i].slice(1);` to add the rest of the letters on the word. `strArr[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase()` will only return the first letter(Capital). You should append the rest by adding `strArr[i].slice(1);`

```js
function titleCase(str) {
  var strArr = str.toLowerCase().split(' ');
  var strUp = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++) {
    strUp[i] = strArr[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + strArr[i].slice(1);
  }
  return strUp.join(' ');
}

console.log(titleCase("I'm a little tea pot"));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Was very helpful. One thing I couldn't grasp tho.Why is length of string bigger than array?Is it cause of null byte ('\0')?

Comment: The length of string is the number of characters while the length of array is the number of elements of the array. On your case, the number of characters will always be greater than when you split by space

Answer (score 1):

You should use the length of the `strArr` in the loop condition:

```
for(var i=0; i <strArr.length;i++)
```

Or just use `for`–`of`.

when you are using the length of the `str` its propably gonna be longer the the length of the `strArr` so it would go out of the array index and that would cause the error.

Answer (score 1):

2 example shown below:

1) UseMapFunction - this is probably the neatest way of doing this, since we are only replacing `val.charAt(0)` for `val.charAt(0).toUpperCase()`

2) More verbose way to do this is using `substring` and a good ole `loop`. Works great as well too.

```js
function UseMapFunction(str) {
     var strArr = str.toLowerCase().split(' ');
     
     var newStrArr = strArr.map(function(val){
      return val.replace(val.charAt(0),val.charAt(0).toUpperCase());
     });
     console.log(newStrArr.join(' '));
}
UseMapFunction("one way to do it is with map");

function UseSubstring(str) {
     var strArr = str.split(' ');
     var newArr =[];
     for (var i = 0; i<strArr.length; i++){
       newArr.push(strArr[i].substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + strArr[i].substring(1,strArr[i].length).toLowerCase());
     }
  console.log(newArr.join(' '));
}
UseSubstring("alternatively use substring and it works fine too");
```